# Changing a website domain and redirecting

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo

We're moving a fairly large website from **domain.one** where it's been for a long time onto **domain.two**. If people still find links for **domain.one** we want them to redirect to an *appropriate* place on **domain.two** (if possible).

**Domian.one** is no longer required after the switch. I don't know anything about moving an entire domain so could use some advice on the best way to go about switching whilst retaining the SEO gained over the years.

Any help is appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in an htaccess file in your root web directory. It will forward your users, and search engines, to the new URL on the new domain.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks also to Bharat for the Webmaster Tools advice.  We're moving forward with Johns advice.

Answer (score 0):

ADD THE FOLLOWING LINES as posted by John .

Also log in to google webmaster tools->configuration->change of address

and change your url ther so that seacrh engine results are also changed.
**THIS iS VERY IMPORTANT**